# How to use Python to analyze the rules of data?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm, rules

I have a set of data, I want to use Python to help analyze it by inputting a new set of data (`x_new`) and deciding the next most likely number. Currently I just replaced the data of iris flower, using `SVC`, but it seems still not accurate enough, the following is my code, can anyone help me improve it?

```py
import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

iris_data = load_iris()
X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(
    iris_data['data'],iris_data['target'],random_state=0)

# make predictions
X_new = np.array([[6,0,5,22]])

from sklearn.svm import SVC
svmClf = SVC(random_state=42)
svmClf.fit(X_train, y_train)
all_pre_and_get_score = svmClf.decision_function(X_new)
all_pre_and_get_score

# Softmax
def Softmax(s : list or np.ndarray):
    S = np.array([np.exp(i) for i in s])
    u = np.sum(S)
    for j in S:
        yield j/u

# Convert to see the probability of the next number appearing
for i in Softmax(all_pre_and_get_score):
    print(i)
    aa = np.array(i)
    bb = aa.tolist()
    m2=bb.copy()
    m2.remove(max(bb))
    m3=max(m2)
    m4=m2.copy()
    m4.remove(max(m2))
    m5=max(m4)
    print()
    print(max(i), '{}'.format(bb.index(max(bb))))
    print(m3,'{}'.format(bb.index(max(m2))))
    print(m5,'{}'.format(bb.index(max(m4))))
```

the data is here:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JJW35qcaHmOcNCUDxidRYYAOGiJk_M1_/view?usp=share_link

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by rules? Usually in a machine learning context that means [decision rules](https://christophm.github.io/interpretable-ml-book/rules.html) used for model interpretability. You can directly use a trained SVM to make predictions on similar data.

Comment: You state: : but it seems still not accurate enough, "  what is your definition of accuracy? What is it you are trying to do?  What is the number you are estimating?